# Search text using c# regex

Tags: c#, regex

Help to find all "rect **NAME** = null" by means of c# regex . (between globals and endglobals)

```
    //Text example:
...
         globals
            ...
        boolexpr cj_true_bool_4896bnao87
        string udg_globals = "endglobals"
        trigger gg_trg___________________________u=null
        rect gg_rct_MyReg1=null
        rect     ra2462346  =            null
            ...
          endglobals
...
```

My code(, working):

1. private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs
   e)
                   {
                       string startglobs = @"^\s*globals\s*$";
                       string endglobs = @"^\s*endglobals\s*$";
                       string currrect = @"^\s*rect\s+(.*)\s*=\s*null\s*";

   ```
                   using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName))
                   {
                       string currline;
                       bool globalstate = false;
                       while ((currline = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                       {
                           /* find globals */
                           Regex startr = new Regex(startglobs);
                           Match startm = startr.Match(currline);
                           if (startm.Success)
                               globalstate = true;


                           /* find endglobls */
                           Regex endr = new Regex(endglobs);
                           Match endm = endr.Match(currline);
                           if (endm.Success)
                               globalstate = false;

                           /* if opened globals find global rect */
                           if (globalstate)
                           {
                               Regex foundrectr = new Regex(currrect);
                               Match foundrectm = foundrectr.Match(currline);
                               if (foundrectm.Success)
                               {
                                   MessageBox.Show(foundrectm.Groups[1].ToString());
                               }
                           }
                       }

                   }

               }
   ```

Comment: You have not shown us your attempt.

Comment: Did you try anything? Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: If attempts weren't successful, why them to show?

Comment: because we just like to know we're not being used for free code, but rather it's a learning experience for you. Also, if another person comes along with the same problems as you've had, they will find the solution here.

Comment: ^\s*globals\s*$ - start

^\s*rect\s*.\s=\s*null\s*


^\s*endglobals\s*$ - end

me need find all strings between rect and =null

but I started studying recently regex

Comment: What is that thing you have in your codeblock??

Comment: Jass Script , me need find all "rect" names in global variables.

Comment: string startglobs = @"^\s*globals\s*$";
            string endglobs = @"^\s*endglobals\s*$";
            string currrect = @"^\s*rect\s*(.*)\\s*=\s*null\s*";

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a hint...

The regex you want is

```
rect (.*)\s?=\s?null
```

You'll now need to learn how to use the regex class to run that, and you might find MatchCollections and Groups interesting.

That's now given you enough to solve your problem in 10 minutes, but you have to do some reading yourself...